# squish qt: How to create QList<QUrl> in squish javascrip

Tags: javascript, qt, squish

Squish claims that we can directly access all QT API from squish script. I am able to create some QT objects in javascript from Squish QT, e.g.

```
// create a new QObject  
let qObject = new QObject();
```

But How can I create a generic type object, say QList<QUrl>??

```
let qlist = new QList();
```

This doesn't work.